# How to make the font smaller in IEEE trans?

Tags: fontsize, ieeetran

How to make the font smaller in IEEE trans? I wish to make the font within the minipage smaller

```
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{8.5cm}$(t_{HSbak}{<}1){\land} (t_{FSbak}{<}1) {\land} (t_{HS}{\geq}2){\land} (t_{FS}{+}t_{HSbak}{\leq}1)$\\
\end{minipage}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the default font switch macros like `\small`, `\footnotesize`, `\tiny`, ...:

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\fbox{%
  \begin{minipage}{8.5cm}
      $(t_{HSbak}{<}1){\land} (t_{FSbak}{<}1) {\land} (t_{HS}{\geq}2){\land} (t_{FS}{+}t_{HSbak}{\leq}1)$%
  \end{minipage}}

\fbox{%
  \small\begin{minipage}{8.5cm}
      $(t_{HSbak}{<}1){\land} (t_{FSbak}{<}1) {\land} (t_{HS}{\geq}2){\land} (t_{FS}{+}t_{HSbak}{\leq}1)$%
  \end{minipage}}

\fbox{%
  \footnotesize\begin{minipage}{8.5cm}
      $(t_{HSbak}{<}1){\land} (t_{FSbak}{<}1) {\land} (t_{HS}{\geq}2){\land} (t_{FS}{+}t_{HSbak}{\leq}1)$%
  \end{minipage}}

\fbox{%
  \tiny\begin{minipage}{8.5cm}
      $(t_{HSbak}{<}1){\land} (t_{FSbak}{<}1) {\land} (t_{HS}{\geq}2){\land} (t_{FS}{+}t_{HSbak}{\leq}1)$%
  \end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

These switches change both the font size, as well as the baseline skip.